# How to have extensible event handler methods in a JavaScript class?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, addeventlistener, es6-class

I have a JavaScript class that runs code when a click occurs. To make that code extensible, I've put it in a separate `handleClick()` method.

However, that's not working ideally because I can't access properties of the class instance via `this`. In the snippet below, `this.bar` is `undefined` when `handleClick()` is being called.

```js
class Foo {
  constructor() {
    this.bar = 42;
    window.addEventListener("click", this.handleClick);
  }

  handleClick() {
    console.log("doing something", this.bar);
  }
}

new Foo();
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the `undefined` issue, create a new property that holds a bound version of the event handler function using [`Function.prototype.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) and use *that* as the event listener. In the snippet below, that's the `handleClickFn` property:

```js
class Foo {
  constructor() {
    this.bar = 42;
    window.addEventListener("click", this.handleClickFn);
  }

  handleClickFn = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  handleClick() {
    console.log("doing something", this.bar);
  }
}

new Foo();
```

Now the class can be extended and everything works as expected:

```js
class Foo {
  constructor() {
    this.bar = 42;
    window.addEventListener("click", this.handleClickFn);
  }

  handleClickFn = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  handleClick() {
    console.log("doing something", this.bar);
  }
}

class FooChild extends Foo {
  handleClick() {
    console.log("doing something else", this.bar);
  }
}

new FooChild();
```

Another approach is to bind the listener to the class instance itself (`this`) and implement the special `handleEvent()` method that the browser calls automatically, as described in [the MDN docs for `addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#the_event_listener_callback):

```js
class Foo {
  constructor() {
    this.bar = 42;
    window.addEventListener("click", this);
  }

  handleEvent(e) {
    if (e.type === "click") {
      this.handleClick();
    }
  }

  handleClick() {
    console.log("doing something", this.bar);
  }
}

class FooChild extends Foo {
  handleClick() {
    console.log("doing something else", this.bar);
  }
}

new FooChild();
```